# substring of String and storing in char

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char, substring

I am taking substring from a string and have to store each character in an `Arraylist`. 
For Example given String is

```
String  s= "abc";
```

I took `ArrayList` and  in for loop stored got  `a  b  c as   characters` using subString as

```
ArrayList<Character> input = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
for (int i=0; i<s.length();i++ )
{
   input= input.add(s.substring(i,1));
}
```

I get error

> The method add(Character) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

How to convert it to char i tried simple typecast but that did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.substring()` returns a `String`, not a character. Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++) {
  char ch = str.charAt(i);
  // do something with it
}
```

Comment: so when i   do this   ch = s.charAt(i);
       input.add(ch);
     System.out.print(input ); ouput is  [a][a, b][a, b, c] why these [] around abc ?

Comment: Cause that's how `ArrayList`s like to print themselves. Don't worry about that.

Comment: so when i use these values further  it will not consider these [ ] and  " , "  just will use  a b c ?

Comment: your ArrayList has 3 elements: `a`, `b`, and `c`. Feel free to use it. To convince yourself `[]` is not really there, do this: `for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i ++) { System.out.println("Character #" + i + ": " + input.get(i)); }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a character to the ArrayList try below:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length();i++ )
{
  input= input.add(new Character(s.charAt(i));

}
```